# Is it possible, with printf, to have the dot "floating" depending on the value?

Tags: c, printf, number-formatting

I want my converted string to always take N characters, a little like this:

```
100000.f -> "00100000.0"
10000.f  -> "00010000.0"
1000.f   -> "00001000.0"
100.f    -> "00000100.0"
10.f     -> "00000010.0"
1.f      -> "00000001.0"
0.1f     -> "00000000.1"
0.01f    -> "0000000.01"
0.001f   -> "000000.001"
0.0001f  -> "00000.0001"
```

or like this:

```
100000.f -> "100000.000"
10000.f  -> "10000.0000"
1000.f   -> "1000.00000"
100.f    -> "100.000000"
10.f     -> "10.0000000"
1.f      -> "1.00000000"
0.1f     -> "0.10000000"
0.01f    -> "0.01000000"
0.001f   -> "0.00100000"
0.0001f  -> "0.00010000"
```

Of course the string can grow larger if the decimal part is too large, but so far I'm not concerned by that.

Should I dynamically generate the "%05.5f" format string?

Comment: No, you should format the number first, then look at the formatted string and figure out whether you want to add leading or trailing padding zeroes.

Comment: If you have an answer @Sam please put it in the answer section so we can peer review it

Comment: What do you expect to get if the number is too small or too large for your format, e.g. `12345678901` or `0.0000000001`?

Comment: You can’t generate these formattings with standard formatting rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to generate string dynamically. You can just do it like this:

```
printf("%0*.5f", width, value);
```

You can customize it even furthrer, to have variable precision:

```
printf("%0*.*f", width, precision, value);
```

Comment: Now you only need to compute width and precision.. ;)

Comment: @rustyx: And the only easy way to do that is via feedback calling a printf-family function and measuring the results.

Answer (score 0):

For the first form, something like:

```
buf[0] = '0';
for (i=0; i<8 && buf[0]=='0'; i++)
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%10.*f", i, x);
```

You can shortcut the search a little bit with `log10(x)`, but you'll still have to test at least two values of `i` since the rounding could change how many digits are needed, and figuring that out is as hard as reimplementing `printf`.

For the second form, something like:

```
for (i=0; i<8 && snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.*f", i, x)<10; i++)
    ;
```